# Markers from API calls not showing in Cordova Google Maps Plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova-plugins, google-maps-api-2

I'm working on displaying google maps location markers using [cordova google maps plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps). I have two API calls, one gets the current location and another one tries to find places around it. Everything is working so for except just showing the places around the current location. The API calls return data as required and promises are fulfilled in sequence. But only displaying on the map does not work. As a matter of fact, hardcoded marker displays, but the API call result data does not get displayed. But im sure that the required data is obtained before trying initialize markers.

Thanks in advance.

```
    var loadMap = function (positions) {

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
            const HOME = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(30.509768899999997, -90.4738385);
            var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(mapDiv, {
                'camera': {
                    'latLng': HOME,
                    'zoom': 12
                }
            });


            map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, function() {


                //hardcoded marker
                map.addMarker({
                    'position': HOME,
                    'title':'My current location'
                });

                // markers from api calls, positions is populated until now as i see in console
                for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
                    map.addMarker({
                        'marker': positions[i],
                        'position': positions[i].position
                    }, function(marker) {
                        marker.on("click", function() {
                            alert(marker.get('marker').title);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    };


    // show map



    // show marker
    getMyLocation()
        .then(function (latLng) {
            console.log(latLng)
            getMarkers(latLng.lat, latLng.lng)
                .then(function (markers) {
                    var pos = [];
                    console.log('pop markes now ... ')
                    markers.forEach(function (item) {
                        console.log();
                        pos.push({
                            'position': new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(item.position[0], item.position[1]),
                            'title':item.title
                        });
                    });

                    console.log(pos);

                    console.log("calling maps ! now .... ")
                    loadMap(pos);
                })
        }, function (reason) {
            console.log(reason);
        });
```

Comment: What is `positions`? I do not see it in the code.

Comment: Its markers .... Im calling loadMap from getMyLocation, its around last lines ... sorry for unclarity

Comment: Can you confirm `positions` is actually defined. `console.log(JSON.stringify(positions, null, 4));` before the `for` loop. If its null, then there's your problem.

Comment: it shows results as expected ...

Comment: can you call markers and locations related functions after map initialization completed ,only call functions not function creation...

Comment: sorry but could you rephrase that ?